# TypeScript Redux AnyAction doesn't accept extraProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I have the following code:

```
//********** From Redux type declarations ************
export interface Action<T = any> {
  type: T
}

export interface AnyAction extends Action {
  // Allows any extra properties to be defined in an action.
  [extraProps: string]: any
}

//***********************************

type ActionHandler<TState> = (state: TState, action: AnyAction) => TState

interface SomeState {
    prop1: number
    prop2: string
}

interface FooAction extends Action {
    prop2: string
}

//This also doesnt work
// interface FooAction extends AnyAction {
//     prop2: string
// }

const foo: ActionHandler<SomeState> = (state: SomeState, action: FooAction): SomeState => {
    return {
        ...state,
        prop2: action.prop2
    }
}
```

And when I compile, I get the following error:

```
Type '(state: SomeState, action: FooAction) => SomeState' is not assignable to type 'ActionHandler<SomeState>'.
  Types of parameters 'action' and 'action' are incompatible.
    Property 'prop2' is missing in type 'AnyAction' but required in type 'FooAction'.ts(2322)
```

Any idea why do I get this error if `AnyAction` allows adding dynamic keys?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51767338/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-strictfunctiontypes-in-typescript

Answer (score 0):

Heyo.

This is because your type above would narrow down the `action` parameter to a subset - but in functions, you can only create functions of the same type that accept a superset of the parameters.
If you want more, read into covariance and contravariance, for example [this article](https://medium.com/@michalskoczylas/covariance-contravariance-and-a-little-bit-of-typescript-2e61f41f6f68) or [this part of the TS changelog](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types)

As for your problem: you can just write your `ActionHandler` type a little different to do the restriction you actually want (see the second generic parameter):

```
//********** From Redux type declarations ************
export interface Action<T = any> {
  type: T
}

export interface AnyAction extends Action {
  // Allows any extra properties to be defined in an action.
  [extraProps: string]: any
}

//***********************************

type ActionHandler<TState, Action extends AnyAction> = (state: TState, action: Action) => TState

interface SomeState {
    prop1: number
    prop2: string
}

interface FooAction extends Action {
    prop2: string
}

//This also doesnt work
// interface FooAction extends AnyAction {
//     prop2: string
// }

const foo: ActionHandler<SomeState, FooAction> = (state: SomeState, action: FooAction): SomeState => {
    return {
        ...state,
        prop2: action.prop2
    }
}
```